# Failed path planning Moveit+RIVZ

Tags: ros, gazebo, rviz, moveit, ur5

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to learn of to do path planning with RVIZ+MoveIt for a UR5 arm. For now I'm trying to simulate only.
I use Gazebo4, RVIZ+MoveIt and universal_robot packages that I built from source for ROS Indigo.

I run these 3 command in 3 different terminal, as written in the universal_robot's README :

```
roslaunch ur_gazebo ur5.launch

roslaunch ur5_moveit_config ur5_moveit_planning_execution.launch sim:=true

roslaunch ur5_moveit_config moveit_rviz.launch config:=true
```

I have several issues and I don't really now what is the origin.
I tried to do path planning from RVIZ, on a simple path from home to up position and from up to home. Sometimes I have "Failed" message in the GUI, sometimes it works. But most of the time it didn't. I struggle to find proper documentation to use the motion planning panel

I have the following error messages

Terminal #2 :

```
[ WARN] [1430368642.447147735, 185.001000000]: Controller  failed with error code PATH_TOLERANCE_VIOLATED
[ WARN] [1430368642.447324161, 185.001000000]: Controller handle  reports status ABORTED
```

Terminal #3:

```
 [ WARN] [1430368548.820347974, 107.047000000]: Fail: ABORTED: Motion plan was found but it seems to be invalid (possibly due to postprocessing). Not executing.
```

If I use the Moveit command-line commander

```
rosrun moveit_commander moveit_commander_cmdline.py
```

And try to "go goal" with goal from "rec c" then modifiy joint angles. Sometimes it works, but I still have this bug sometimes :

```
manipulator> go goal
[ INFO] [1430370662.457107039, 2110.983000000]: ABORTED: Solution found but controller failed during execution
Failed while moving to goal
```

I run it in VirtualBox and I can have 8 FPS in RVIZ.

EDIT : I notice than even if I ask for simple joint movement

```
  group.set_joint_value_target([1.5, 0, 1.5, 0, 0, 0])
  group.go()
```

I have the error

```
[ WARN] [1430368642.447147735, 185.001000000]: Controller  failed with error code PATH_TOLERANCE_VIOLATED
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/208208/failed-path-planning-moveit+rivz/) by [Arowana](https://answers.ros.org/users/22294/arowana/) on ROS Answers with karma: 381 on 2015-04-30

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2015-04-30**:
Are you using the pkg from apt-get, or github? If you were the one who created the `moveit_config package` you're using, I would say you just have to create controller configs (see [this](http://goo.gl/2aXQbu).

**Comment by [Arowana](https://answers.ros.org/users/22294/arowana/) on 2015-04-30**:
from apt-get for all of them except universal_robot packages, I build it from indigo branch of the git repo,
The arm move most of the time, it means that the controller is configured.
I have the errors messages but not always.
Moreover I don't have any message related to wrong controller config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I moved to a powerful PC. I installed Ubuntu 14.04 and all needed packages.
The problem is gone. Seems that the controller was not able to compute fast enough, because before it was very slow in VM.

I am not sure of why this thing happened.

---

Originally posted by [Arowana](https://answers.ros.org/users/22294/arowana/) with karma: 381 on 2015-05-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [budekatude](https://answers.ros.org/users/31120/budekatude/) on 2017-07-12**:
Is there no way to just slow down the execution of the planned trajectory so as to give the computer more time for the calculations?
I ran into the same kind of issues and don't really have the opportunities to switch over to a more powerful computer...